# golang how can I use struct name as map key

Tags: go

```
type A struct {
    a1 int
    a2 string
}
type B struct {
    b1 int
    b2 string
}
type C struct {
    c1 int
    c2 string
}
```

there are 3 structs, I want put the names into a map as key, and process func as map value

(instead of type-switch)

input arg is a interface, use for loop to judge what struct this interface is. And process this arg by process func in map value.
about:

```
var funcMap map[structName]func(arg){A:processA, B:processB, C:processC}

func testFunc(arg) {
    for k, v in range funcMap {
        if k == reflect.TypeOf(arg) {
            v(arg)
        }
    }
}
```

how can I build this map??? hope code, thanks!   (^o^)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to index your map on `reflect.Type`:

```
type funcMapType map[reflect.Type]func(interface{})

var funcMap funcMapType
```

then to register a type with a function:

```
funcMap[reflect.TypeOf(A{})] = func(v interface{}) { log.Println("found A") }
```

if your function needs to modify the struct, you'll need to register a pointer to the struct type:

```
funcMap[reflect.TypeOf(&A{})] = func(v interface{}) { log.Println("found *A") }
```

https://play.golang.org/p/LKramgSc_gz

Comment: for other readers: don't forget that `reflect.TypeOf(A{}) != reflect.TypeOf(&A{})`. Types must be [identical](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_identity)

Comment: how to handle pointer to struct as key? example: *A?

Comment: @xiangyuhaoaizcm updated answer & playground-link with pointer logic.